# Can I configure Vim to go to the end of particular file?

Tags: vim, modeline

I have a text file that I append some text to. I would like to configure Vim to go to the end of this particular file each time I open it.

How do I do this for a single file?

Comment: I really don't see any point of configuring vim for this purpose as it can simply be accomplished by pressing `shift+g` in normal mode which will take you to the end of the file. Also by simply pressing `gg` (in normal mode) will take you to the start of the file. I think anyone has this much time to be able to press one or two key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you put the following line into your vimrc, it will move the cursor to the last line of *your-file-name.txt* when you open it:

```
autocmd BufRead your-file-name.txt normal G
```

It will not, however, leave you in insert mode. If you also want to start inserting when you read the file, you need a slightly more complicated line in your vimrc:

```
autocmd BufRead your-file-name.txt execute "normal G$"|startinsert!
```

Comment: And how do I change mode from normal to insert for that file?

Comment: @REACHUS, in that case you need to change the autocmd to `autocmd BufRead your-file-name.txt execute "normal G$"|startinsert!`.

Answer (score 0):

if you're on a linux or on mac, you can use "tail"

tail -f n20 filename.log

^ this will keep showing the new lines. 
the file will be showing the 20 last lines.

Comment: The first sentence in the question states that they want to append text to the file.  Tail doesn't do this.

Comment: my bad :( ....will read better, I thought he was writing into from somewhere else.